# UIPageViewController: how to add a non-paging toolbar or other "overlay" elements?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented a PDF viewer. Currently it is a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIPageViewController`.
My toolbar, some overlay elements (like quick access to certain pages of the PDF) are added to the standard `UIViewController's` view.
However I wonder if that is required? Would it be somehow possible to inherit from `UIPageViewController` and have the paging effect for sub controllers and still have "floating" elements on top that won't be paged?
or is the containment the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should create `UIPageViewController` programmatically and add its view to another `UIViewController`'s view as a subview. And the elements that we want them to be 'overlay' should be subviews of the host `UIViewController`.

For example, in `- viewDidLoad`:

```
UIPageViewController *pvc = // init this on your own way
pvc.dataSource = // your data source

// Set page view controller's view's frame to match host view's frame
pvc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

// And here comes the magic
[self.view insertSubView:pvc.view belowSubview:<any subview>];
```

Briefly we only use `UIPageViewController`'s view but not itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that SO is intended to be more of a question & answer resource than a help forum, so it doesn't matter if the question is old or if the asker is even still interested. Posting answers for the benefit of others who encounter the same problem and find the thread in a search is entirely in line with SO's mission, and highly encouraged if a suitable answer hasn't been posted yet.

Comment: That's the dirty solution of what I meant with view controller containment. Instead of using the proper way, you're just adding one view controllers view into another.

Comment: well it's a legit answer and lets you add a non-paging toolbar or other "overlay"  element. So it delivers. Since this is what is being asked.

Comment: @Cad And it will probably suffer from all kinds of issues related to UIController events, like rotation. I have already two controllers and they use UIViewController containment. Injecting the view as a subview isn't any different from that but still the wrong way to do it.

Comment: View controller containment and 'subview'ing would be considered the same but it's a working solution, and just tried rotation, it works. Thinking of any possible performance issues, but it's just changing the view from one to another. I wonder why do you think this is a wrong way to do it.